# GoogleAppEngine root:php failure(255)

Tags: google-app-engine, boot

Every time I run `dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path /opt/local/bin/php-cgi54 phpintern/` under OS X, this error is returned:

```
INFO     2013-05-24 01:59:15,523 sdk_update_checker.py:244] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-05-24 01:59:15,712 sdk_update_checker.py:260] Update check failed: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
WARNING  2013-05-24 01:59:15,719 api_server.py:329] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-05-24 01:59:15,723 api_server.py:153] Starting API server at: http://localhost:64606
INFO     2013-05-24 01:59:15,727 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-05-24 01:59:15,734 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR:root:php failure (255) with:
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.15
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: require_once(google/appengine/runtime/ApiProxy.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php on line <i>21</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>245760</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>../setup.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>246736</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{closure:/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php:2-40}(  )</td><td title='/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>../setup.php<b>:</b>41</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0012</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>257864</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{closure:/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php:20-32}(  )</td><td title='/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>../setup.php<b>:</b>38</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-fatal-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'google/appengine/runtime/ApiProxy.php' (include_path='/Users/lazyGoose0412/Job_work/google_appengine/helloworld:/usr/local/bin/php/sdk') in /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php on line <i>21</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>245760</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>../setup.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>246736</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{closure:/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php:2-40}(  )</td><td title='/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>../setup.php<b>:</b>41</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0012</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>257864</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{closure:/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php:20-32}(  )</td><td title='/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>../setup.php<b>:</b>38</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

And after that, the appserver keeps binding my 8080 port. I need to kill the bound port and re-launch the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the right answer from hakre: )

The problem is I also have a **python version Google-App-engine**. In order to solve this this problem, I need to specify the "dev_appserver" to **PHP-GAE-SDK**

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/opt/local/bin/php-cgi54 phpintern/
```

Comment: it doesn't help... The same error occurs again.I have AppEngine of Python version in my computer. It there anything wrong with that?