# GoogleAppEngine PHP issue

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm running dev_appserver.py PHP runtime in MAC OS, according to the instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld

But at localhost:8080 I keep getting:

```
Warning: require(index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php on line 103

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'index.php' (include_path='/Users/evelynrios/Documents/JavaScript/JSON:AJAX/BayAreaBikeShare:/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/php/sdk') in /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php on line 103
```

A previous user posted this answer, here:
[GoogleAppEngine root:php failure(255)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725829/googleappengine-rootphp-failure255)

"I got the right answer from hakre: ) 
The problem is I also have a python version Google-App-engine. In order to solve this this problem, I need to specify the "dev_appserver" to PHP-GAE-SDK"

But I have no idea what that means and there is no further explanation on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be a bad directory name.